What is the original statement and proof of the Schwarz Reflection Principle?
In the lectures of Prof. McKernan https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~jmckerna/Teaching/19-20/Spring/120B/l_22.pdf one can find a beautiful proof of the following Strong form of the Schwarz Reflection Principle:
Theorem 22.6. Let $U$ be a region symmetric about the real axis and
let $U^+ = \{ z ∈ U\ |\ \text{Im}\ z > 0 \}$ be the part of $U$ in the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$. If $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function on $U^+$ such that $\underset{\text{Im}\ z→0^+}{\lim} \text{Im}\ f(z) = 0$ as $z$ approaches the real axis from above then $f(z)$ extends to a holomorphic function $f=f^e$ on $U$ which satisfies
$f(\overline{z}) = \overline{f(z)}$ for all $z ∈ U$.
It seems to me this Strong form of the Schwarz Reflection Principle was the original form in which Schwarz himself formulated his Reflection Principle. To this suggestion I arrived reading the formulation and proof given on pages 443-446 of the book "Théorie des fonctions" by Georges Valiron - second edition 1948, which proof is based on (given there interesting application of) Schwarz's lemma. No harmonic function are used there. The basic idea is to use the Cauchy's formula for a circle with its center, say $z_0$, belonging to $\overline{U^+}\cap\mathbb{R}$ with the extended by reflection function $f^e$ in order to define for $z\in U$, with $\text{Im}\ z \le 0$ and prove analyticity of $f^e$ in $U$ including - at all points $z\in U$, with $\text{Im}\ z = 0$.
Now, the question/s is/are:
(1) Was the abovementioned Strong form of the Schwarz Reflection Principle the original form of the Schwarz Reflection Principle presented by Schwarz himself? The same question about the proof from the abovementioned book of Valiron. Please provide evidences.
(2) Is there some more reachable proof, if possible in English, of this Strong form of the Schwarz Reflection Principle, based only on "pure" complex analysis but not on harmonic functions?

I knew (also used Schwarz's lemma) but still did mistakes. I am sorry! Thanks a lot for helping! I think I corrected all the appearances of the mistake. If any more, please help again!

For (2), this is essentially the proof given in Henri Cartan’s book at the end of chapter 2. His assumption is slightly different: he assumes $f$ is continuous in the intersection of the closed upper half plane with $U$, and that $f$ takes real values on the real axis. This allows the reflection argument to go through.

Ok, but that means you are talking about The weak form of the Schwarz Reflection Principle, which does not answer my question (2). This proof (based on Morera's theorem) in Henri Cartan's book is really beautiful proof of The weak form of the Schwarz Reflection Principle. It indeed does not make (direct) use neither of Cauchy's formula, nor of harmonic functions.

I found a useful (I believe) link. Somebody with good understanding of German possibly cold help us find the answer of question (1) at least. I am not saying nor excluding as a possibility that the original formulation and proof could be found in the paper of Schwarz  Ueber einige Abbildungsaufgaben. Aus einer Mittheilung an Herrn Richelot in Königsberg. Journal für reine und angewandte Mathematik, Band 70, Seite 105—120, which is on pages 65 - 83 in the link. Here it is the link: https://ia802206.us.archive.org/10/items/gesammeltemathem02schwuoft/gesammeltemathem02schwuoft.pdf
